# can the hdtv be used as a monitor for the Dell Latitude 6410

Tags: video, display, hdtv, dell-latitude

can a  hdtv be used as a monitor for the Dell Latitude 6410

Answer (score 1):

If you have a VGA port on the back of the HDTV, sure.  Also, does the laptop have and HDMI out ports? You could also use that if you have a HDMI port.